# CoreData app crashes when deleting row from TableView

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, swift4

I have a dozen table view controllers that all work as expected, then I have this one which crashes with:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

The code doing this has been modified several times with different options but to no effect.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class QTypeVCY: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
{
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        let sections = frc.sections
        return sections!.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        guard let sections = self.frc.sections else
        {
            fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
        }
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QQQQ", for: indexPath)

        let qtype = frc.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = qtype.title

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete
        {
            do
            {
                let qtype = frc.object(at: indexPath)
                let context = self.frc.managedObjectContext
                context.delete(qtype)
                try context.save()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            catch
            {
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        } else if editingStyle == .insert
        {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }

    lazy var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<Qtype> =
        {
            let context = self.app.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let req: NSFetchRequest<Qtype> = Qtype.fetchRequest()
            req.fetchBatchSize = 10

            let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Qtype.specialty), ascending:true)
            let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Qtype.title), ascending:true)
            req.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]

            let afrc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: req, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

            afrc.delegate = self
            do
            {
                try afrc.performFetch()
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                fatalError("Abort while fetching Qtype")
            }
            return afrc
    }()
}
```

The crash occurs on the tableview.deleteRows statement. I have tried surrounding the code with beginUpdate/endUpdates, with and without the performFetch, even tried re-entering the code in case I had a typo that I missed. This same basic code is working fine on other tables/view controllers, just this one.

The entity is just made up of strings. I had it with and without relationships to other entities.

[image: Qtype Entity]

The row is deleted since the next time I run the app it is missing. Also, one other thing about this table is that calling reloadData after adding a new object does not add the row. I need to leave the tableview and reenter it. I'm sure the two are related but can't say why.

Since originally posting this, I included the entire VC code instead of just the offending code. I have also tried swapping the Entity with a different entity where this issue does not occur, but the program still crashes even with a different entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could offer the actual solution, but the above code now works. I had updated XCode to the 1/24/18 version but I don't think that is the solution. I also stripped out a few things I had in the original code that crashed, but then I put them back and it still works. I suspect I had a typo somewhere, but after spending a half hour trying to locate it, I'm declaring victory and moving on.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to remove the item also from the data source array

```
let qtype = qtypes[indexPath.row]
let context = self.frc.managedObjectContext
context.delete(qtype)
try context.save()
qtypes.remove(at: indexPath.row) // <-- 
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Comment: That didn't do it.  I should have shown more code.  The array qtypes isn't a global, it was retrieved from the datastore.

Comment: Nevertheless you have to remove the item from the array representing the data source array.

Comment: I tried doing that and the same problem persists. I modified the example to show where the array comes from.

Comment: Do you use the delegate methods of the `FetchedResultsController`? If yes you must not remove the row *manually*. And if `sections` is value type you have to reassign `qtype` to the sections. And forget `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. The lines have no effect.

Comment: I am using delegate methods and only added the beginUpdates and endUpadates after trying other possibilities.  I have this same basic setup in a dozen other views and this is the only one with this issue.

Comment: Once again, if you are using the delegate methods you must remove the `deleteRows` line because the controller removes the row via the delegate method.

Comment: I removed the deleteRows and it indeed did avoid the crash problem, but even if I add tableView.reloadData() the row remains, although with a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I just solloved a problem similar to yours.
when deleted data in CoreData, TableView data array also delete before `appDelegate.saveContext()`

Code in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

```
self.tableviewArrayData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
appDelegate.saveContext()
```